# What's wrong with this SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

The following query returns "ORA-00904 error: SATIS: Invalid identifier." When I remove the line `HAVING satis > 0`, it works. What should I do?

```
SELECT donem, bolge_adi, sehir_tasra "1=Ş, 2=T", 
       COUNT(DISTINCT mekankodu) "M.SAYISI",
       SUM(b2b_dagitim + b2b_transfer - b2b_iade) satis
FROM mps_view2
WHERE donem IN ('200612','200712','200812','200912')
AND (ob IS NOT NULL OR b2b_ob IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY donem, bolge_adi, sehir_tasra
HAVING satis > 0
ORDER BY donem, bolge_adi, sehir_tasra
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not use alias in conditions (having section of your query)

try this one:

```
SELECT donem, bolge_adi, sehir_tasra "1=Ş, 2=T", 
   COUNT(DISTINCT mekankodu) "M.SAYISI",
   SUM(b2b_dagitim + b2b_transfer - b2b_iade) satis
FROM mps_view2
WHERE donem IN ('200612','200712','200812','200912')
      AND (ob IS NOT NULL OR b2b_ob IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY donem, bolge_adi, sehir_tasra
HAVING SUM(b2b_dagitim + b2b_transfer - b2b_iade) > 0
ORDER BY donem, bolge_adi, sehir_tasra
```

Comment: @Mehper: this rule is common in SQL Server and Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

From here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm

> The alias can be used in the
>   order_by_clause but not other clauses
>   in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to

```
SELECT donem, bolge_adi, sehir_tasra "1=Ş, 2=T",  
       COUNT(DISTINCT mekankodu) "M.SAYISI", 
       SUM(b2b_dagitim + b2b_transfer - b2b_iade) satis 
FROM mps_view2 
WHERE donem IN ('200612','200712','200812','200912') 
AND (ob IS NOT NULL OR b2b_ob IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY donem, bolge_adi, sehir_tasra 
HAVING SUM(b2b_dagitim + b2b_transfer - b2b_iade) > 0
ORDER BY donem, bolge_adi, sehir_tasra
```

*You cannot use the alias in the HAVING clause.*