# Why is selecting specified columns, and all, wrong in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, table-alias, ora-00936

Say I have a select statement that goes..

```
select * from animals
```

That gives a a query result of all the columns in the table.

Now, if the 42nd column of the table `animals` is `is_parent`, and I want to return that in my results, just after `gender`, so I can see it more easily. But I also want all the other columns.

```
select is_parent, * from animals
```

This returns `ORA-00936: missing expression`.

The same statement will work fine in Sybase, and I know that you need to add a table alias to the `animals` table to get it to work ( `select is_parent, a.* from animals ani`), but *why* must Oracle need a table alias to be able to work out the select?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I am transitioning from SQL Server to Oracle. I am seeing the same error.

Comment: This behavior is ISO/ANSI SQL standard compliant. A single `*` must be alone in the <select list>.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually, it's easy to solve the original problem. You just have to qualify the *.

```
select is_parent, animals.* from animals;
```

should work just fine. Aliases for the table names also work.

Comment: I would never put "*" in production code, but this is the work around I needed.  I was doing some "hunting" and was trying something like         Select (ColA || ',' || ColB) as "CompoundPK", * from MYTABLE.  Thanks for the alias workaround.  Upvote.

Comment: In Oracle 11.2, you may have to qualify both '*' and the column 'is_parent'.

Answer (score 2):

There is no merit in doing this in production code.  We should explicitly name the columns we want rather than using the SELECT * construct.

As for ad hoc querying, get yourself an IDE - SQL Developer, TOAD, PL/SQL Developer, etc - which allows us to manipulate queries and result sets without needing extensions to SQL.

Comment: `Select *` in the real world is indeed dangerous. I've been caught up before when columns are added and `*` is used in procedures. However, for adhoc queries, my statement was entirely valid.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good answers so far on why `select *` shouldn't be used and they're all perfectly correct. However, don't think any of them answer the original question on why the particular syntax fails.

Sadly, I think the reason is... "because it doesn't".

I don't think it's anything to do with single-table vs. multi-table queries:

This works fine:

```
select *
from
    person p inner join user u on u.person_id = p.person_id
```

But this fails:

```
select p.person_id, *
from
    person p inner join user u on u.person_id = p.person_id
```

While this works:

```
select p.person_id, p.*, u.*
from
    person p inner join user u on u.person_id = p.person_id
```

It might be some historical compatibility thing with 20-year old legacy code.

Another for the "buy why!!!" bucket, along with [why can't you group by an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235883/why-wont-oracle-sql-let-us-use-aliases-in-conditions)?

Comment: The negative is a little harsh. I think only Rene and myself to date have answered the question asked. All the other answers just say that "select *" shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2):

Good question, I've often wondered this myself but have then accepted it as one of those things...

Similar problem is this:

```
sql>select geometrie.SDO_GTYPE from ngg_basiscomponent

ORA-00904: "GEOMETRIE"."SDO_GTYPE": invalid identifier
```

where geometrie is a column of type mdsys.sdo_geometry.

Add an alias and the thing works.

```
sql>select a.geometrie.SDO_GTYPE from ngg_basiscomponent a;
```

Answer (score 1):

The use case for the alias.* format is as follows

```
select parent.*, child.col
from parent join child on parent.parent_id = child.parent_id
```

That is, selecting all the columns from one table in a join, plus (optionally) one or more columns from other tables.

The fact that you can use it to select the same column twice is just a side-effect. There is no real point to selecting the same column twice and I don't think laziness is a real justification.

Comment: I know that if you use multiple tables that you need to define which one to return all columns for, but I was wondering why Oracle can't work out what table I mean when it has a choice of one table. In addition, I find a `select column, *` used when debugging saves time compared to trying to copy out the columns and porting them into Excel, manually moving columns around with the risk of mismatching datacolumns.

Answer (score 1):

`Select *` in the real world is only dangerous when referring to columns by index number after retrieval rather than by name, the bigger problem is inefficiency when not all columns are required in the resultset (network traffic, cpu and memory load).
Of course if you're adding columns from other tables (as is the case in this example it can be dangerous as these tables may over time have columns with matching names, `select *, x` in that case would fail if a column x is added to the table that previously didn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

> **why** must Oracle need a table alias to be able to work out the select

Teradata is requiring the same. As both are quite old (maybe better call it *mature* :-) DBMSes this might be historical reasons.

My usual explanation is: an unqualified `*` means *everything/all columns* and the parser/optimizer is simply confused because you request *more than everything*.