# How to resolve 'ambiguous column naming in select list' when 'select col, t.*' is used with an order by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

This is related to:
[Why is selecting specified columns, and all, wrong in Oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315295/why-is-selecting-specified-columns-and-all-wrong-in-oracle-sql)

The query:

```
select is_parent, animals.* from animals order by is_parent
```

throws the error:

```
[Error] ORA-00960: ambiguous column naming in select list
```

Which makes sense as `is_parent` is duplicated.

Can anyone tell me a simple fix for this, as the original query `select is_parent, animals.* from animals` is very nice and quick to return all other columns. I looked at this [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00960.php) but the technique to remove the ambiguity does not seem to apply.

Comment: select is_parent as is_parent1 ... order by _parent1

Comment: thanks, that is possible, if not the most convenient when you have multiple things you are selecting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to come up with a neat solution thanks to the very helpful comments and answers that say that I will confuse the compiler if I don't use an alias.

I find having to rename the columns cumbersome, for example, if I had selected more columns:

```
select is_parent, age, animals.* from animals order by is_parent, age
```

The quick and dirty solution is to tell Oracle to order using column numbers:

```
select is_parent, age, animals.* from animals order by 1, 2
```

This removes the ambiguity in column names.

Answer (score 2):

Something you can try:

1) Use the table name (or its alias) in the ORDER BY clause:

```
SQL> select is_parent, animals.*
  2  from animals
  3  order by animals.is_parent;

no rows selected
```

2) Write your ordering clause based on the position of fields in your select list:

```
SQL> select is_parent, animals.*
  2  from animals
  3  order by 1;

no rows selected
```

3) Use an alias for explicitly written columns:

```
SQL> select is_parent as parent, animals.*
  2  from animals
  3  order by is_parent;

no rows selected
```

Each of these solutions may be more or less readable; the second is the easiest one, and seems to match you need to order by the "most important" fields.
However, I would not recommend any of these in writing an application, using them only for one-shot queries.

Comment: This seems to be the most complete answer. I ended up using option 2 as it is much easier in my case to use column numbering in the order clause instead of adding extra text.

Answer (score 1):

Use a alias name. Like:

```
select is_parent as check_is_parent, animals.* from animals order by is_parent
```

Answer (score 1):

you get is_parent column for two times, so its create ambiguity.
Use alias Like :

`select is_parent as is_parent1, animals.* from animals order by is_parent1`

Answer (score 1):

As there are 2 column names with the same name, so Oracle throws the error. Use an alias for the column name as

```
select is_parent as PARENT, animals.* from animals order by is_parent
```

Work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you duplicating the column name as * will return all columns?

Either use this

```
select animals.* from animals order by is_parent
```

or explicitly type out all the columns

Comment: because the table contains hundreds of columns, I want to see the important ones out first, followed by the rest to do diagnostics. The linked question provides an example of why this query structure is very convenient.

Comment: @Alex then you would have to alias them, else you would confuse the compiler and get that error