# FROM keyword not found where expected when selecting * + counting

Tags: oracle, select, count

So i have this table, and and in ORACLE would like to select all data + do a count.

I tried

```
SELECT *, count(*) as count
FROM ...
```

but i get the error message:

> ERROR: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected ...

```
CONTROLNAME   BRANDNAME   GROUPTYPES    GROUPNAME 
ECU           AUDI        VERNETZER         1 
ECU           AUDI        FUSI              2 
ECU2          AUDI        FACHANWENDER  Keine zuordnung 
ECU3          AUDI        FACHANWENDER  Keine zuordnung
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to qualify the table name, e.g. `SELECT yourTable.*, count(*) FROM ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is selecting specified columns, and all, wrong in Oracle SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315295/why-is-selecting-specified-columns-and-all-wrong-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: and you should use a "group by" if using count(*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name.*, count(*) over () as count
FROM   table_name...;
```

Comment: you should add group by

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar - in Oracle that is not necessary (if you aggregate over the entire table).